# Space after command with \write

Tags: spacing, write-file

I did not see this question yet, correct me if there is.

It's not the usual problem of adding a space after a command. It's more specifically when writing to a file. For some reason the same method does not apply when using the `\write` command.

**Minimal working example:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Insert{Insert}

\begin{document}

% write to pdf
\Insert stuff.\par % wrong method
\Insert\ stuff.\par   %
\Insert{} stuff.\par  % all valid methods
\Insert~stuff.\par    %

% open file to write to
\immediate\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=filename.txt
\newcommand\writefile{\immediate\write\file}

% write the same to file
\writefile{\Insert stuff.}
\writefile{\Insert\ stuff.}
\writefile{\Insert{} stuff.}
\writefile{\Insert~stuff.}

% close file
\immediate\closeout\file


\end{document}
```

**Output pdf:**

> Insertstuff.
>   Insert stuff.
>   Insert stuff.
>   Insert stuff.

**Output filename.txt**

```
Insertstuff.
Insert\ stuff.
Insert{} stuff.
Insert\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M \ {}stuff.
```

Which is not quite what I need or expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TeX ignores spaces after control sequences (formed by letters) *and* performs complete expansion when doing a `\write`.

The tokens it sees when you do `\writefile{\Insert stuff.}` are (separated by • just for clarity)

```
\Insert•s•t•u•f•f•.
```

and there's *no* space. The expansion gives

```
Insertstuff
```

When you put a pair of braces, the space after them is not ignored (it doesn't follow a control sequence):

```
\Insert•{•}• •s•t•u•f•f•.
```

With `\Insert\ stuff` it's the same: the token "control space" is unexpandable, so you get

```
Insert\ stuff.
```

With `\Insert~stuff` you lose: the complete expansion of `~` is not what you'd expect: it's the set of instructions necessary to "print a non breaking space". Indeed LaTeX has `\protected@write` to cope with this kind of commands that should not be expanded during a write.

As zeroth explained, the expansion of `\space` is a space; but it's *not* ignored after `\Insert`, because when TeX is reading tokens it doesn't yet see the expansion of `\space`, but that token (which undoubtedly isn't a space token).

Answer (score 9):

For writing spaces in output files you need the explicit `\space`. Therefore you just do:

```
\writefile{\Insert\space stuff.}
```

Comment: That's strange, but ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

```
\writefile{\noexpand\Insert stuff.}
```

Or if you don't need the write to be immediate:

```
\protected@write\file{}{\protect\Insert stuff.}
```