# how to print variable value of \draw function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use this function:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

    \begin{document}
        \newcommand{\xmax}{14}
        \newcommand{\fmin}{(pi/3)}
        \newcommand{\fmax}{(2*pi)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [domain=\xmax:0, samples=500]


    % The following line uses linear frequency increase
    %\draw[ultra thick, red] plot (\x, {sin(deg((\fmin+\x*((\fmax-\fmin))/\xmax)*\x))} );
    % The following line uses exponential frequency increase
    \draw[ultra thick, red] plot (\x, {sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))} );
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I need to evaluate the `\x` parameter.
How can I print it's value?
also on log file is ok

Renato

Comment: Please don't post just code fragments. Make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that also includes how all the variables are defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print all the points that the `draw...plot` is using, you can:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\xmax}{14}
\newcommand{\fmin}{(pi/3)}
\newcommand{\fmax}{(2*pi)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [domain=\xmax:0, samples=500]
    \draw[ultra thick, red] plot (\x, {sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))} );
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{\xmax/500}
\foreach \x in {0,\step,...,\xmax} {
    \x, \qquad 
    \pgfmathparse{sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))}\pgfmathresult
    \par
}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

(continuing...)

If you want the output on the log file, you can add (after the par, for example)

```
 \wlog{x is \x\space and the function \pgfmathresult}
```

and you'll have in your `.log` file:

```
x is 0 and the function 0.0
x is 0.028 and the function 0.02939
x is 0.056 and the function 0.05899
x is 0.084 and the function 0.08878
x is 0.112 and the function 0.11867
```

For the strange `\space`, see [Space after command with \write](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63596/space-after-command-with-write)

Clearly, to have it *only* on the log file, use as the loop:

```
\foreach \x in {0,\step,...,\xmax} { 
        \pgfmathparse{sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))}
        \wlog{x is \x\space and the function \pgfmathresult} 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't give us much information in your question, so I'm just using some dummy numbers....

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\def\x{0.5}
\def\xmax{1}
\def\fmin{1}
\def\fmax{5}


\pgfmathparse{sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))}\pgfmathresult


\end{document}
```